# Memory usage analysis of a c program using ps aux or top

Tags: c, memory, memory-leaks, malloc, ps

Our teacher told us to allocate 500 bytes per second and analyse it with

```
> ps aux
```

command on linux.

Original Question (in German) (feel free to translate it with Google, it translates quite accurately)

```
(c) Schreiben Sie ein einfaches Programm, das im Sekundentakt 500 Byte Speicher anfordert.Starten Sie das
Programm und uberprüfen Sie den Speicherplatzverbrauch zur Laufzeit.Was stellen Sie fest? Erklären Sie ihre
Beobachtung.(Hinweis: Sie können die "time.h"Bibliothek für sekundentakte Operation benutzen.)
```

which translates into English:

> Write a simple program, which requests at one second intervals 500
>   bytes of memory. Start the program and check the usage of the storage
>   space at run-time. What do you notice? (Note: You can utilize the
>   "time.h" library for one-second operation.)

I allocated even more and made it faster, but still couldn't see clear results, even though I theoretically was supposed to.

My C program (if I don't leak any memory) always uses 0.0% %MEM, even though it was mathematically supposed to be using more (I have 16gb ram, 16 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 = 17179869184 Bytes, 17179869184 / 1000 = 17179869.184 Bytes correspond to 0.1% of my RAM, before getting to `INT_MAX` I could allocate 2147400500 Bytes of memory, which is more than 0.1% of my memory (12.4%), but still shows 0%... on `ps aux` or top)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //for system() and malloc
time_t start;
char *job, *temp;
int printMenu(){
    //linux : clear, windows : cls, ..
    system("clear");
    printf("\nEnter: Wiederhole (fuer 60 Sekunden), Andere Zeichen: Quit\n");
    printf("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n");
}

void delay(int mics){

    clock_t timeDelay = (mics-0.9999) * CLOCKS_PER_SEC + clock();
    while(timeDelay > clock());
}

int end(){
    delay(1);
    system("ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt");
    delay(1);
    free(job);
    time_t end = clock();
    printf("\nTotal time elapsed: end-start clock: %lf\n", (double)(end - start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

    return 0;

}
int main(){
    int exitstatus;
    int x = 500;
    start = clock();
    exitstatus = system("ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt");

    // printf("%ld cps\n", CLOCKS_PER_SEC); // 1,000,000 oder (1takt = 1 mikrosekunde)
    system("gnome-terminal -e top -t check_memory");
    printMenu();
    char s = '\n'; // enter
    job = (char *)malloc(x);
    if(job == NULL)
    {
        printf("Allocation failed!");
        return end();
    }
    while(s == '\n')
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < 990; i++)
        {
            x += 100000;
            printf("Allocating %d Bytes..\n", x);
            /*
                job = (char *)malloc(x);
                if(job == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Malloc failed!");
                    return end();
                }
            */  
            /*
            temp = realloc(job, x);
            if( temp != NULL)
            {
                job = temp;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Reallocation failed!");
                return end();

            }
            */


            free(job);
            temp = (char *)malloc(x);
                if(temp == NULL)
                {
                    printf("Malloc failed!");
                    return end();
                }
                else
                {
                    job = temp;
                }

           delay(1);

        }

        exitstatus = system("ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt");

        printf("\nEnter: Wiederhole (fuer 60 Sekunden), Andere Zeichen: Quit\n");

        scanf("%c", &s);
        if(exitstatus != 0)
        {
            printf("Terminal couldn't run 'ps'");
        }
    }


    return end();

}
```

Output on Terminal:

```
Allocating 2146600500 Bytes..
Allocating 2146700500 Bytes..
Allocating 2146800500 Bytes..
Allocating 2146900500 Bytes..
Allocating 2147000500 Bytes..
Allocating 2147100500 Bytes..
Allocating 2147200500 Bytes..
Allocating 2147300500 Bytes..
Allocating 2147400500 Bytes..
Allocating -2147466796 Bytes..
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Output on memreport.txt

```
inducti+ 21367  0.0  0.0  22948  1148 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21365  0.0  0.0   4624   784 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364  0.0  0.0   4372   708 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21364  0.0  0.0 101188  1488 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21382  0.0  0.0  22948  1108 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21380  0.0  0.0   4624   832 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364  7.0  0.0 197864  1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21387  0.0  0.0  22948  1048 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21385  0.0  0.0   4624   800 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 10.6  0.0 294544  1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21390  0.0  0.0  22948  1080 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21388  0.0  0.0   4624   772 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 14.0  0.0 391224  1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21393  0.0  0.0  22948  1052 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21391  0.0  0.0   4624   804 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 18.0  0.0 487904  1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21396  0.0  0.0  22948  1008 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21394  0.0  0.0   4624   808 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 16.0  0.0 584584  1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21399  0.0  0.0  22948  1016 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21397  0.0  0.0   4624   820 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 18.7  0.0 681264  1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21402  0.0  0.0  22948  1084 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21400  0.0  0.0   4624   800 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 21.5  0.0 777944  1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21405  0.0  0.0  22948  1104 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21403  0.0  0.0   4624   804 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 24.2  0.0 874624  1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21408  0.0  0.0  22948  1060 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21406  0.0  0.0   4624   804 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 27.0  0.0 971304  1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:01 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21411  0.0  0.0  22948  1008 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21409  0.0  0.0   4624   828 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 29.5  0.0 1067984 1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:01 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21414  0.0  0.0  22948  1004 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21412  0.0  0.0   4624   820 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 32.5  0.0 1164664 1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:01 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21417  0.0  0.0  22948  1088 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21415  0.0  0.0   4624   876 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 35.2  0.0 1261344 1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:01 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21420  0.0  0.0  22948   968 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21418  0.0  0.0   4624   776 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 30.2  0.0 1358024 1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:01 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21423  0.0  0.0  22948  1008 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21421  0.0  0.0   4624   808 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 32.6  0.0 1454700 1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:01 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21426  0.0  0.0  22948  1036 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21424  0.0  0.0   4624   784 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 34.8  0.0 1551380 1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:01 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21429  0.0  0.0  22948  1004 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21427  0.0  0.0   4624   812 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 30.8  0.0 1648060 1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:01 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21432  0.0  0.0  22948  1032 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21430  0.0  0.0   4624   820 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 32.8  0.0 1744740 1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:01 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21435  0.0  0.0  22948  1088 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21433  0.0  0.0   4624   772 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 34.6  0.0 1841420 1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:02 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21438  0.0  0.0  22948  1000 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21436  0.0  0.0   4624   820 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 36.6  0.0 1938100 1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:02 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21441  0.0  0.0  22948  1052 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21439  0.0  0.0   4624   784 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 38.5  0.0 2034780 1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:02 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21444  0.0  0.0  22948  1004 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21442  0.0  0.0   4624   832 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 21364 34.1  0.0   4504  1552 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:02 ./2c.out
inducti+ 21447  0.0  0.0  22948  1004 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 21445  0.0  0.0   4624   804 pts/0    S+   21:40   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
```

If I don't use free, and use one of the commented out blocks to allocate memory, My %MEM goes up to 0.04%

```
job = (char *)malloc(x);
if(job == NULL)
{
   printf("Malloc failed!");
   return end();
}
```

But that is leaking memory.

Does the result of ps aux and top commands only show leaked memory, if so, how does it make any sense?

I tried to google the answers, but I couldn't find anything satisfying, I do believe in googling, please don't just link to an already given answer which wouldn't explicitly apply to this one.

Some final notes

> I know that the delay() function doesn't delay for 1 second, but less, I made it temporarily so, only to see the results faster
>
> if I use the alternative code block for memory allocation that I showed, I also get the "terminal couldn't run 'ps'" error, the reasoning behind which is unclear to me...

I appreciate any kind of help you may offer, thank you :)
And I'm sorry if the question is too intricate or unclear.

Edit:
Calloc didn't work, but tried initialising every block with 'a' 's and memory went up to 1.1%

```
inducti+ 25073  0.0  0.0  22948  1104 pts/2    S+   23:01   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 25071  0.0  0.0   4624   804 pts/2    S+   23:01   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 25070  0.0  0.0   4372   716 pts/2    S+   23:01   0:00 ./2c.out
inducti+ 25070  101  0.6 101188 98212 pts/2    S+   23:01   0:18 ./2c.out
inducti+ 25091  0.0  0.0  22948  1052 pts/2    S+   23:02   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 25089  0.0  0.0   4624   880 pts/2    S+   23:02   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 25070 94.9  1.1 197864 194900 pts/2   S+   23:01   1:13 ./2c.out
inducti+ 25103  0.0  0.0  22948  1028 pts/2    S+   23:02   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 25101  0.0  0.0   4624   820 pts/2    S+   23:02   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
inducti+ 25070 91.3  1.1 197864 194900 pts/2   S+   23:01   1:13 ./2c.out
inducti+ 25107  0.0  0.0  22948  1052 pts/2    S+   23:03   0:00 grep ./2c.out
inducti+ 25105  0.0  0.0   4624   780 pts/2    S+   23:03   0:00 sh -c ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt
```

But I could still use some explanations about why this all happens.

Comment: Try actually writing data to the allocated memory. On most operating systems malloc() doesn't actually allocate physical memory, it just allocates address space. It doesn't allocate physical memory until it is used. It is likely that your OS doesn't even check whether it could guarantee to supply the physical memory when needed. This is called "overcommit".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried calloc, problem persists.

Comment: calloc doesn't necessarily cause the memory to be written to. The OS could, for example, map each allocated memory page to the same physical page filled with zeros and as long as you only read the page it doesn't matter. Attempting to write to the page will cause a page fault and cause the kernel to allocate physical memory. Try writing at least one non-zero value every 4096 bytes.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to initialize every block with 'a', and memory went up to 1.1%, which prove your theory right. I still don't know how memory leak is related to this issue and how it makes my system("ps ... grep ..") function fail, but this will be sufficient for my submission.

Comment: To the OP: please look up what VSIZE and RSS means. Or CopyOnWrite.

Comment: BTW I should have mentioned that not allocating physical memory typically only happens for malloc/calloc that cause a whole page or more to be allocated for the request (typically anything more than 2K with a 4K page size). For sizes less than that then the memory allocated will share pages with other allocations. In this case most implementations of malloc/calloc will write control information immediately before the allocated block (e.g number of bytes allocated) so physical memory would be used.

Comment: @wildplasser thank you, after reading your comment I've read about VIRT and RES sections of 'top' and now I superficially understand the difference between virtual and physical memory usage.

Comment: But can someone please explain why the {{{{{system("ps aux --sort -pmem | grep './2c.out' >> memreport.txt");}}}} returns -1 when I use                                                                                                                                   {{{{job = (char *)malloc(x);
if(job == NULL)
{
   printf("Malloc failed!");
   return end();
}}}}}